# docker build context and sensitive data

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The title of this question might suggest that it has already been answered, but trust me, I searched intensively here on SO :-)

As I understand it when building a docker-image the current folder will be packaged up and sent to the docker-deamon as the build-context. From this build-context the docker-image is build by "ADD"ing or "COPY"ing files and "RUN"ning the commands in the Dockerfile.

And furthermore: In case I have sensitive configuration-files in the folder of the DockerFile, these files will be sent to the docker-deamon as part of the build-context.

**Now my question:**
Lets say I did not use any COPY or ADD in my Dockerfile... will these configuration files be included somewhere in the docker-image? I ran a bash inside the image and could not find the configuration-files, but maybe they are still somewhere in the deeper layers of the image?

**Basically my question is: Will the context of the build be stored in the image?**

Answer (score 1):

Only things you explicitly `COPY` or `ADD` to the image will be present there.  It's common to have lines like `COPY . .` which will copy the entire context into the image, so it's up to you to check that you're not copying in things you don't want to have persisted and published.

It still is probably a good idea to keep these files from being sent to the Docker daemon at all.  If you know which files have this information, you can add them to a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) (syntax similar to `.gitignore` and similar files).  There are other ways to more tightly control what's in the build context (by making a shadow install tree that has only the context content) but that's a relatively unusual setup.

Answer (score 1):

As you said only `COPY`, `ADD` and `RUN` operations create layers, and therefore, only those operations add something to the image.

The build context is only the directory with the resources those operations (specifically `COPY` and `ADD`) will have access to while building the image. But it's not anything like a "base layer".

In fact, you said you ran bash and double checked that nothing sensitive was there. Another way to make sure about this is by checking the layers of the image. To do so, `docker history --no-trunc <image>`